# return signal from ResolveFn

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-signals

In my angular app there can be 2 type of layout(e.g. List and Detail).
I have to get the layoutConfig based on activated route. For this I'm using a route resolver.
My plan is ResolveFn will return a signal not an observable.
My *LayoutService* has an additional requirement, if its a List, it will get list data from layoutConfig's serviceUrl.
Below is my existing code which pass url as parameter and return an observable:

```
export const LayoutResolver: ResolveFn<LayoutConfig> = (
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
) => {
    const _layoutService = inject(LayoutService);
    _layoutService.setCurrentActivatedRoute(state.url);
    return _layoutService.layoutConfig$;
};
```

```
export class LayoutService {
  #httpClient = inject(ApiHttpService);
  readonly #url_layout: string = 'listConfig';

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      console.log('currentActivatedRoute', this.CurrentActivatedRouteSig());
    });
  }

  CurrentActivatedRouteSig = signal<string | undefined>(undefined);
  setCurrentActivatedRoute(url: string) {
    this.CurrentActivatedRouteSig.set(url);
  }
  currentActivatedRoute$ = toObservable(this.CurrentActivatedRouteSig);
  
  layoutConfig$ = this.currentActivatedRoute$
    .pipe(
      filter(Boolean),
      switchMap(x => this.#httpClient.GETT<LayoutConfig>(`${this.#url_layout}`)
        .pipe(
          map(x => x.data)
        ))
    );
  LayoutConfigSig = toSignal(this.layoutConfig$, { initialValue: undefined });

  private gridData$ = toObservable(this.LayoutConfigSig)
    .pipe(
      tap(x => console.log('gridData$ =>', x)),
      filter(Boolean),
      switchMap(x => this.#httpClient.GETT<any>(x.serviceUrl)
        .pipe(
          tap(x => console.log('serviceUrl$ =>', x.data)),
          map(x => x.data)
        ))
    )

  GridDataSig = toSignal(this.gridData$, { initialValue: [] });
}
```

I'm expecting *LayoutConfigSig* and *GridDataSig(if List)* in my component as Signal.
Also, I'm unsure whether *CurrentActivatedRoute* in my service class should be signal or a Subject?